# C++ Кириллица в выводе

Tags: c++, консоль

При выводе кириллицы в консоль, выводятся какие-то непонятные символы.
Раньше, до переустановки VS, все работало исправно, без дополнительных строчек кода (!).
С чем данное явление может быть связано?

Answer (score 0):

Вероятно операционная система Windows?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1371012/how-do-i-print-utf-8-from-c-console-application-on-windows
Рекомендуют использовать SetConsoleOutputCP( 65001 );

Что касается "а почему раньше работало", так это зависит от конкретной настройки системы (где-то внутри можно сказать, что все консольные окна будут писать юникодом, по умолчанию пишут одной из 8-бит кодировкой).

Вот еще ссылка https://superuser.com/questions/269818/change-default-code-page-of-windows-console-to-utf-8

В поисковике ищи "utf-8 console windows"